# mindmap design for readability

Tags: tikz-pgf, map

I have this MWE for a mindmap with statistical tests (in Portuguese)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,calc}
\definecolor{azul}{RGB}{35, 140, 255}
\tikzset{grow cyclic list/.code={%
        \def\tikzgrowthpositions{{#1}}%
        \foreach \n [count=\i,remember=\i]in {#1}{}%
        \let\tikzgrowthpositionscount=\i%
        \tikzset{growth function=\tikzgrowcycliclist}}}
\def\tikzgrowcycliclist{%
    \pgftransformshift{%
        \pgfpointpolar{\tikzgrowthpositions[mod(\the\tikznumberofcurrentchild-1,\tikzgrowthpositionscount)]}%
        {\the\tikzleveldistance}}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[grow cyclic, text width=2.7cm, align=flush center,every node/.append style={circle,
            fill=azul!5,
            inner sep=-20pt},
            level 1/.style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=100},
            level 2/.style={level distance=3.5cm,sibling angle=50},
            level 3/.style={level distance=3.5cm,sibling angle=45}]
\node[]{\textbf{Testes de Hipóteses}}
child [] { node (tnp) {\textbf{Não Paramétricos}}
    child { node {Uma População}
        child { node {$\chi^2$ de ajustamento}}
        child { node {Wilcoxon para a mediana}}}
    child { node {Duas Populações}
        child { node {Amostras Independentes}
            child { node {Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney}}
            child { node {$\chi^2$ Independ.}}}
        child { node {Amostras Emparelhadas}
            child { node {Wilcoxon}}
            child { node {$\chi^2$ McNemar}}}
    }
    child { node {Duas ou mais Populações}
        child{ node {Amostras Independentes}
            child { node {Kruskal-Wallis}}}
        child { node {Amostras Emparelhadas}
            child { node {Friedman}}}   
    }
}
child [] { node (tp) {\textbf{Paramétricos}}
    child { node {Uma População}
                child { node {\textit{t}-Student média}}
    child { node {Z proporção}}
    }
    child { node {Duas Populações}
    child { node {Amostras Independentes}
    child { node {\textit{t}-Student difs. médias}}
    child { node {Z para a difs. proporções}}
    }
    child { node {Amostras Emparelhadas}
    child { node {\textit{t}-Student difs. médias}}
    child { node {Z difs. proporções}}}
}
    child { node {Duas ou mais Populações}
        child { node {Amostras Independentes}
            child { node {ANOVA \textit{one-way} e \textit{two-way}}}}  
        child { node {Amostras Emparelhadas}
            child { node {ANOVA de Medições Repetidas}}}
}}; 
\node[annotation, fill=white, text width=22mm] at ($(tp.south) + (-0., -0.75)$){\small $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$};
%\node[annotation, fill=white, text width=16mm] at ($(tp.north) + (-1, 0.5)$){\small $\sigma^2_1=\ldots \sigma^2_k$};
%\node[annotation, fill=white, text width=12mm] at ($(tp.north) + (1.1, 0.5)$){\small $\sigma^2_1=\sigma^2_2$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with which I get this mindmap:

[image]

The mind map has to fit in a letter sized page.  My design is ugly and crowded. I wonder if someone, with design skills better than mine, can produce something cleaner and readable....

Thanks!

Comment: Don't do a mindmap then. It provides no overview. A normal tree where the root is the "center" of the mindmap would be better, in my opinion. Or just a indented list.

Comment: Maybe ask on graphic design? But I don't know how easy it might be to help without knowing the purpose of the diagram i.e. what's being communicated, what's important etc. There are lots of repeated nodes which suggests something about the way this is organised isn't working, so I doubt it is just a question of making a prettier mindmap.

Comment: Do not place the parametric/non parametric  division on the root but as final binary node the tip of each branch, without duplicating testing conditions (i,e., only a node for two  related populations, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

Just as a conceptual idea, you could follow the inventive principle (ip) of `doing a little less`, combined with ip `(progressive) segmentation`.

This could mean:

- breaking the big mindmap into several smaller ones
- where each one of it shows a little less
- like so, where you re-align as needed, e.g. more from left to right (more comments below) :

Overall:

[image: main]

---

Parametric branch:

[image: parametric]

---

Non-parametric branch:

[image: nonparametric]

---

You could also do a bit more, by following the ip of `asymmetry` for better readability. E.g. the diagrams would be more readable, when readers could identify the level of a child at a glance, e.g. by:

- using different shapes per level
- using different color, hue, grading per level
- modifying the connecting lines depending on the level (thicker, thinner etc.)
- as long as it's a prominent difference or change (font size probably won't)

---

I struggle with your code, as there seems to be no way to turn the circles into ellipses, one of the nodes standard shapes. This may be due to the mindmap-library.

However, if you'd draw 3 smaller trees, you could use all other tikz approaches, which may be easier to control, like:

- drawing ordinary nodes and lines
- using the `positioning` lib
- using matrix for positioning (see tutorials in pgfmanual)
- using `chain`, `tree` etc.