# Flow chart without space

Tags: flow-charts

I working with the following Flow chart:

[image]

I used this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}  

\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{changepage}  

 \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning}  
  \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=green!80,text width=3.5em, text centered, 
 nodedistance=3.1cm,]   
  \tikzstyle{document} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!30,text width=4.7em, text centered, node distance=2.5cm,]   
  \tikzstyle{block1} = [rectangle, draw, fill=green!50,text width=4.5em, text centered, rounded corners, node distance= 3cm, minimum height=3em]  
  \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=yellow!50,text width=4.5em, text centered, rounded corners, node distance=2.25cm, minimum height=4em]  
  \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']  
  \tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, rectangle ,text centered, fill=red!50, node distance=2cm, minimum height=3em]  

  \tikzstyle{ioi} = [trapezium, draw, trapezium right angle=120,rounded corners, fill=blue!60, node distance=2.8cm, minimum height=2.7em]  
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, draw, trapezium right angle=110,rounded corners, fill=red!20, node distance=1.9cm, minimum height=2.9em]  


\begin{document}


\begin{adjustwidth}{-0.2cm}{-0.2cm}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.8cm, auto] 

    \node [cloud] (init) {\textbf{  $Star$}};  
    \node [decision, below of=init](A){$(u_{1},\pm v_{1})$ yes, $(\pm u_{0},v)$ not, };  
    \node [decision, left of = A, xshift=-1.5 cm](A1){$(\pm u_{0},v)$ yes, $(u_{1},\pm v_{1})$ not, Sec. \ref{ste12cas1}}; 
    \node [decision, right of = A, xshift=1cm](A2){$(u_{1},\pm v_{1})$ and $(\pm u_{0},v)$ yes}; 
    \node [document, below of=A1, xshift=-2cm, yshift=-1cm](B){Cases {\bf 1a.} to {\bf 1.f}, Prop. \ref{pro3ste12}, Prop. \ref{pro1ste4}};  
    \node [document, below of=A1, xshift=2cm, yshift=-1cm](B1){Cases {\bf 2a.} to {\bf 2.f}, Prop. \ref{pro3ste12}, Prop. \ref{pro1ste96b}}; 
    \node [decision, below of = B,xshift=-1cm, yshift=-0.5cm](C){$\varphi(p)$, 1 or 3 roots, Remark \ref{rem1ste6}};  
    \node [decision, below of = B1,xshift=1cm, yshift=-0.5cm](C1){$\varphi(p)$, 1 or 3 roots, Remark  \ref{rem1ste6}}; 
    \node [document, below of=C, xshift=-1.5cm](CC1){1 root, $p_{0}$};
    \node [document, below of=C, xshift=1.5cm](CC2){3 roots, $p_{0,1,2}$}; 
    \node [document, below of=C1, xshift=-1.5cm](C1C){1 root, $p_{0}$};
    \node [document, below of=C1, xshift=1.5cm](C2C){3 roots, $p_{0,1,2}$};
    \node [block, below of=CC1](CC11){Theo. \ref{the1ste91a}\\ Theo. \ref{the2ste91a}\\ Theo. \ref{the3ste91a}};
    \node [block, below of=CC2](CC21){Theo. \ref{the4ste91a}};
    \node [block, below of=C1C](C1C1){Theo. \ref{the1ste96b}\\ Theo. \ref{the2ste96b}\\ Theo. \ref{the3ste96b}};
    \node [block, below of=C2C](C1C2){Theo. \ref{the5ste91a}};
    
    \path [line] (init) -- (A);   
    \path [line] (init) -- (A1); 
    \path [line] (init) -- (A2); 
    \path [line] (A1) -- (B);   
    \path [line] (A1) -- (B1); 
    \path [line] (B) -- (C);  
    \path [line] (B1) -- (C1); 
    \path [line] (C) -- (CC1); 
    \path [line] (C) -- (CC2); 
    \path [line] (C1) -- (C1C); 
    \path [line] (C1) -- (C2C); 
    \path [line] (CC1) -- (CC11); 
    \path [line] (CC2) -- (CC21); 
    \path [line] (C1C) -- (C1C1); 
    \path [line] (C2C) -- (C1C2); 
    
\end{tikzpicture}  
    \end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

My problem is that I need put below the other desicions below $Start$ similar structures to desicion in the left, how I can do it?
I want the flow chart to look like this

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please add a little more to your last paragraph, or may be a sketch? I'm not sure, what you look for. Thank you

Comment: Do you know how nodes and paths work in tikz? This should be relatively simple if you know that. Have you consulted the tikz manual?

Comment: Hi @MS-SPO, I uploaded the sketch. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. // There are several ways to do it. One is specifying the distance between nodes. More straight forward in this case may be to position the top nodes right below Start at absolute coordinates, and keep the others as relative positions: whenever the diagram becomes too crwoded, you adjust just the 3 coords. (You may want to position Start ABOVE the middle node for simplicity.) // BTW, the trapezium shape seems to cause trouble. So if you don't really need it, I suggest to replace it.

Comment: Hi. But I don't  understand what means absolute coordinate and relative position. Could you help, at least in the first lines the code? the other I find that I can.

Comment: Please see my answer (solution).

Answer (score 1):

Here I'll elaborate on my proposal, made in the comments, with a focus on absolute and relative coordinates/positions.

#### Positions

In `tikz` you can use the following position related statements:

- `\node (A) at (1,5) {};    % ABSOLUTE coordinate at (1,5)`
- `\node[below=of A] (B) {}; % RELATIVE to (A), needs \usetikzlibrary{positioning}`
- `\node (C) {};             % IMPLICITLY put at (0,0)`

So most of the time you may want to specify the nodes coordinate by the first two.

#### Transfer to your code

The following code:

- uses class `standalone`, which is more useful when developing such graphics
- places the middle decision `(A)` ABSOLUTE `at (0,0)`
- places `(init)` RELATIVE to `(A)` `[above=of A]`
- places the other two decisions `(A1)` and `(A2)` at different ABSOLUTE coordinates
- leaves the rest untouched, but pruned a little

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.8cm, auto] 
Let's demonstrate:

    % ~~~ new root node at (0,0), which is an absolute position ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node [decision]            (A) at (0,0)        {$(u_{1},\pm v_{1})$ yes, $(\pm u_{0},v)$ not, };  

    % ~~~ placing node (init) RELATIVE to (A), above a ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node [cloud, above=of A]   (init)  {\textbf{  $Star$}};  
    
    % ~~~ placing the left decision (A1) at new ABSOLUTE coordinate (-10,0) ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node [decision]    (A1) at (-10,0) {$(\pm u_{0},v)$ yes, $(u_{1},\pm v_{1})$ not, Sec. \ref{ste12cas1}}; 
    
    % ~~~ placing the right decision (A2) at new ABSOLUTE coordinate (15,0) ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node [decision]    (A2) at (+15,0) {$(u_{1},\pm v_{1})$ and $(\pm u_{0},v)$ yes}; 
    
    % ~~~ rest, in fragments ... ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node [document, below of=A1, xshift=-2cm, yshift=-1cm](B){Cases {\bf 1a.} to {\bf 1.f}, Prop. \ref{pro3ste12}, Prop. \ref{pro1ste4}};  
    \node [document, below of=A1, xshift=2cm, yshift=-1cm](B1){Cases {\bf 2a.} to {\bf 2.f}, Prop. \ref{pro3ste12}, Prop. \ref{pro1ste96b}}; 
    \node [decision, below of = B,xshift=-1cm, yshift=-0.5cm](C){$\varphi(p)$, 1 or 3 roots, Remark \ref{rem1ste6}};  
    \node [decision, below of = B1,xshift=1cm, yshift=-0.5cm](C1){$\varphi(p)$, 1 or 3 roots, Remark  \ref{rem1ste6}}; 

    
    \path [line] (init) -- (A);   
    \path [line] (init) -- (A1); 
    \path [line] (init) -- (A2); 
    \path [line] (A1) -- (B);   
    \path [line] (A1) -- (B1); 
    \path [line] (B) -- (C);  
    \path [line] (B1) -- (C1); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

#### Observations

For class `book` your diagram seems to be too big. I suggest to follow a different approach, e.g. like [described here on tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/692169/245790).

#### Results and code

The first diagram displays my description made above. The second shows your code for comparision.

[image: results]

```
%\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}  
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone} % better during development of the flowchart

\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{changepage}  

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning}  

  \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=green!80,text width=3.5em,
                          text centered, node distance=3.1cm,]% <<< typo !!!
  \tikzstyle{document} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!30,text width=4.7em, 
                          text centered, node distance=2.5cm,]   
  \tikzstyle{block1}   = [rectangle, draw, fill=green!50,text width=4.5em, 
                          text centered, rounded corners, node distance= 3cm, minimum height=3em]  
  \tikzstyle{block}    = [rectangle, draw, fill=yellow!50,text width=4.5em,
                          text centered, rounded corners, node distance=2.25cm, minimum height=4em]  
  \tikzstyle{line}     = [draw, -latex']  
  \tikzstyle{cloud}    = [draw, rectangle ,text centered, fill=red!50, node distance=2cm, minimum height=3em]  

  \tikzstyle{ioi}      = [trapezium, draw, trapezium right angle=120,rounded corners, fill=blue!60, 
                          node distance=2.8cm, minimum height=2.7em]  
  \tikzstyle{io}       = [trapezium, draw, trapezium right angle=110,rounded corners, fill=red!20, 
                          node distance=1.9cm, minimum height=2.9em]  


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.8cm, auto] 
Let's demonstrate:

    % ~~~ new root node at (0,0), which is an absolute position ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node [decision]            (A) at (0,0)        {$(u_{1},\pm v_{1})$ yes, $(\pm u_{0},v)$ not, };  

    % ~~~ placing node (init) RELATIVE to (A), above a ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node [cloud, above=of A]   (init)  {\textbf{  $Star$}};  
    
    % ~~~ placing the left decision (A1) at new ABSOLUTE coordinate (-10,0) ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node [decision]    (A1) at (-10,0) {$(\pm u_{0},v)$ yes, $(u_{1},\pm v_{1})$ not, Sec. \ref{ste12cas1}}; 
    
    % ~~~ placing the right decision (A2) at new ABSOLUTE coordinate (15,0) ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node [decision]    (A2) at (+15,0) {$(u_{1},\pm v_{1})$ and $(\pm u_{0},v)$ yes}; 
    
    % ~~~ rest, in fragments ... ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node [document, below of=A1, xshift=-2cm, yshift=-1cm](B){Cases {\bf 1a.} to {\bf 1.f}, Prop. \ref{pro3ste12}, Prop. \ref{pro1ste4}};  
    \node [document, below of=A1, xshift=2cm, yshift=-1cm](B1){Cases {\bf 2a.} to {\bf 2.f}, Prop. \ref{pro3ste12}, Prop. \ref{pro1ste96b}}; 
    \node [decision, below of = B,xshift=-1cm, yshift=-0.5cm](C){$\varphi(p)$, 1 or 3 roots, Remark \ref{rem1ste6}};  
    \node [decision, below of = B1,xshift=1cm, yshift=-0.5cm](C1){$\varphi(p)$, 1 or 3 roots, Remark  \ref{rem1ste6}}; 

    
    \path [line] (init) -- (A);   
    \path [line] (init) -- (A1); 
    \path [line] (init) -- (A2); 
    \path [line] (A1) -- (B);   
    \path [line] (A1) -- (B1); 
    \path [line] (B) -- (C);  
    \path [line] (B1) -- (C1); 
\end{tikzpicture} 


%\begin{adjustwidth}{-0.2cm}{-0.2cm}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.8cm, auto] 
    \node [cloud] (init) {\textbf{  $Star$}};  
    \node [decision, below of=init](A){$(u_{1},\pm v_{1})$ yes, $(\pm u_{0},v)$ not, };  
    \node [decision, left of = A, xshift=-1.5 cm](A1){$(\pm u_{0},v)$ yes, $(u_{1},\pm v_{1})$ not, Sec. \ref{ste12cas1}}; 
    \node [decision, right of = A, xshift=1cm](A2){$(u_{1},\pm v_{1})$ and $(\pm u_{0},v)$ yes}; 
    \node [document, below of=A1, xshift=-2cm, yshift=-1cm](B){Cases {\bf 1a.} to {\bf 1.f}, Prop. \ref{pro3ste12}, Prop. \ref{pro1ste4}};  
    \node [document, below of=A1, xshift=2cm, yshift=-1cm](B1){Cases {\bf 2a.} to {\bf 2.f}, Prop. \ref{pro3ste12}, Prop. \ref{pro1ste96b}}; 
    \node [decision, below of = B,xshift=-1cm, yshift=-0.5cm](C){$\varphi(p)$, 1 or 3 roots, Remark \ref{rem1ste6}};  
    \node [decision, below of = B1,xshift=1cm, yshift=-0.5cm](C1){$\varphi(p)$, 1 or 3 roots, Remark  \ref{rem1ste6}}; 
    \node [document, below of=C, xshift=-1.5cm](CC1){1 root, $p_{0}$};
    \node [document, below of=C, xshift=1.5cm](CC2){3 roots, $p_{0,1,2}$}; 
    \node [document, below of=C1, xshift=-1.5cm](C1C){1 root, $p_{0}$};
    \node [document, below of=C1, xshift=1.5cm](C2C){3 roots, $p_{0,1,2}$};
    \node [block, below of=CC1](CC11){Theo. \ref{the1ste91a}\\ Theo. \ref{the2ste91a}\\ Theo. \ref{the3ste91a}};
    \node [block, below of=CC2](CC21){Theo. \ref{the4ste91a}};
    \node [block, below of=C1C](C1C1){Theo. \ref{the1ste96b}\\ Theo. \ref{the2ste96b}\\ Theo. \ref{the3ste96b}};
    \node [block, below of=C2C](C1C2){Theo. \ref{the5ste91a}};
    
    \path [line] (init) -- (A);   
    \path [line] (init) -- (A1); 
    \path [line] (init) -- (A2); 
    \path [line] (A1) -- (B);   
    \path [line] (A1) -- (B1); 
    \path [line] (B) -- (C);  
    \path [line] (B1) -- (C1); 
    \path [line] (C) -- (CC1); 
    \path [line] (C) -- (CC2); 
    \path [line] (C1) -- (C1C); 
    \path [line] (C1) -- (C2C); 
    \path [line] (CC1) -- (CC11); 
    \path [line] (CC2) -- (CC21); 
    \path [line] (C1C) -- (C1C1); 
    \path [line] (C2C) -- (C1C2);    
\end{tikzpicture}  
%    \end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @MS-SPO, but in my case still with your code the flowchart goes out of the margins, but I  change the diamonds with rectangles and my flowchart improved, Thanks again.

Comment: Right. See my remarks under "Observations". Though you can adjust size a little using scale AND transform shape within the tikszpicture, text will probably be too small. So think of fragmenting your diagram,as indicated.